# How to get the full "path" to a node using the ast (Abstract Syntax Trees) module?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm tinkering with Python's [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html) (Abstract Syntax Trees) module.

Using `ast.NodeVisitor`, it is possible to walk a source tree and display information such as each node's name like so:

```py
class MyAST(ast.NodeVisitor):      

     def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
         print(node.col_offset * " " +node.name)         
         self.generic_visit(node)   

     def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):         
         print(node.col_offset * " " + node.name)     
         self.generic_visit(node)
```

It can then be used on any piece of code like this:

```py
tree = ast.parse(open("/path/to/file.py").read())
MyAST().visit(tree)
```

This will output something like (e.g. used on [models.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kennethreitz/requests/master/requests/models.py) from the [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) package):

```
RequestEncodingMixin                                                                                                                                                         
    path_url                                                                                                                                                                 
    _encode_params                                                                                                                                                           
    _encode_files                                                                                                                                                            
RequestHooksMixin                                                                                                                                                            
    register_hook                                                                                                                                                            
    deregister_hook                                                                                                                                                          
Request                                                                                                                                                                      
    __init__
    __repr__
    prepare
(...)
```

I would like to know, for a given node, the full "path" to it. In the above output sample, when I'm in the `FunctionDef` node `deregister_hook`, I would like to know that its parent is `ClassDef` `RequestHooksMixin` so that I could output something like `RequestHooksMixin.deregister_hook`.

Answer (score 0):

`ast.NodeVisitor` is not designed with nesting levels in mind, so it isn't the best tool for producing an output with level-based indentation.

Instead, you can use [`ast.iter_child_nodes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.iter_child_nodes) to visit the immediate child nodes of each node recursively, and output the node and increase the indentation level when it's of a class or a function:

```
import ast

def build_tree(node):
    def _visit(node, level=0):
        if isinstance(node, (ast.ClassDef, ast.FunctionDef)):
            yield node.name, level
            level += 1
        for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
            yield from _visit(child, level)
    return '\n'.join(f'{"    " * level}{name}' for name, level in _visit(node))
```

so that:

```
source = '''
class Foo:
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method2(self):
        pass

class Bar:
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method2(self):
        pass
'''
print(build_tree(ast.parse(source)))
```

outputs:

```
Foo
    method1
    method2
Bar
    method1
    method2
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/aQHqbi